# spl_autoload_register doesn't seem to be register the class

Tags: php, nginx, php-7

I'm working on a simple MVC, It works on localhost but not in production server.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in /var/www/html/inc/route.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/inc/route.php on line 3
```

Nginx rewrite rule:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?return=$1 last;
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
 require_once "./inc/autoload.php";
 require_once "./inc/route.php";
?>
```

autoload.php

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($includeName) {

 if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../class/'.$includeName.'.class.php')) {
  $pathClass = strtolower(__DIR__ .'/../class/'.$includeName.'.class.php');
  require_once($pathClass);
 }

});

spl_autoload_register(function($includeName) {

  if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../controllers/'.$includeName.'.php')) {
   $pathController = strtolower(__DIR__ .'/../controllers/'.$includeName.'.php');
   require_once($pathController);
 }

});
?>
```

This is just simply confusing me.

Edit: Adding /class/route.class.php and /inc/route.php

route.class.php

```
<?php
  class Route {
    public static $validRoutes = array();
    public static function set($route, $function) {
    public statis $url = $_GET['return'];
    if(empty(self::$url) == 1) {
    public static $url = "index"
    }
      self::$validRoutes[] = $route;
      if($url == $route) {
        $function->__invoke();
      } else {
        echo "Route not found";
      }
    }
  }
 ?>
```

route.php

```
<?php

  Route::set('index.php', function() {
    echo "Home";
  })

 ?>
```

Comment: Does the file `/var/www/html/inc/route.php` actually have a Class definition named `Route`?

Comment: strtolower(__DIR__ .'/..//lass/'.$includeName.'.class.php'); - lass?

Comment: @Randall the class is in a class file, The autoloader, its in class/route.class.php (which should be loaded.)

Comment: @vasa_c Not the issue, was a typo when I was re-writing it. It's correct in the real file.

Comment: Right, but the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in /var/www/html/inc/route.php` ... Class "Route" is not found in that file. Wrong file? Wrong class name?

Comment: @Randall It's because everything is done through the index page.

Autoload loads the class,
Routes has the routes.

Example route page `Route::set('index.php',function() { echo "Index";}`

Comment: Please include a snip from route.php then.

Comment: @Randall Added snippets to the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You look `file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../class/'.$includeName.'.php')` - Route.php and then use strtolower() and attempt include route.php

Comment: Just me going so fast, skimming trying to figure it out. Flew right over my head.

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for file like `class/Route.class.php` instead of `class/route.class.php`.

You can use this autoload which does exactly the same thing (without the bug) and seems cleaner:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {

  // Get parent directory and filename
  $baseDir = dirname(__DIR__);
  $fileName = strtolower($className) . '.class.php';

  // List directories to search for class
  $dirs = [
    $baseDir . '/class',
    $baseDir . '/controllers',
  ];

  // Search a class in every directory
  foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    if (file_exists($dir . '/' . $filename)) {
        // Class file exists, include and return
        include($dir . '/' . $filename);
        return;
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: I gave up +1 rep, even though it doesn't show up cause I'm under 15. As I found the answer. I am extremely thankful thanks.